# Indexing VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql, index, unique-constraint

Should I add `INDEX` to my `VARCHAR` column? I need to select rows with a string, not with ID, will it speed my queries?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `slug` = 'new-york';
```

Comment: What is a slug?

Comment: Yes. you can but the field should be an index key

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ A slug is the part of a URL which identifies a particular page on a website in an easy to read form. For example, SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `slug` = 'new-york';

Comment: *Should I add UNIQUE constraint to my slug column? I need to select rows with a slug, will it be helpful?* No. Constraint is not relative to performance.

Comment: @Akina In MYSQL `UNIQUE` automatically adds `INDEX` to the column. By  saying "Should I add `UNIQUE` constraint to my slug column?" I mean that should I add `INDEX` to my column?

Comment: Index - maybe yes, maybe no (dependent by the query text and condition expression selectivity). Unique constraint - no. *In MYSQL UNIQUE automatically adds INDEX to the column.* No. In MySQL there exists unique indices (including primary) and non-unique indices. Index "constraint" keyword (except foreign) is excess.

Answer (score 2):

You plan to have queries of the type:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE slug = 'new-york';
```

So, yes, you should definitely have an index on `(slug)`.

Should it be `UNIQUE` index or a `UNIQUE` constraint?

That depends on whether you allow to have two rows in the table with same "slug". I think this is unlikely to be a requirement, as "slugs" are usually short terms to uniquely identify a thing (user, city, country, web page, etc).

So, yes, the index should be `UNIQUE`. MySQL makes no difference between `UNIQUE INDEX` and `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. I prefer to use the `UNIQUE` constraint syntax (which adds a `UNIQUE` index):

```
ALTER TABLE cities 
    ADD CONSTRAINT cities_slug_uq     -- constraint name
        UNIQUE cities_sluq_uqx        -- index name
        (slug) ;
```